# /getSiteRefreshInfo contains siteAddStatus=ADD_FAILURE

Tags: yodlee

in production, I can experience this kind of response from yodlee after starting a site refresh (via jsonsdk/Refresh/startSiteRefresh), I keep getting the same /getSiteRefreshInfo response (jsonsdk/Refresh/getSiteRefreshInfo):

```
{
  "siteRefreshStatus": {
    "siteRefreshStatusId": 1,
    "siteRefreshStatus": "REFRESH_TRIGGERED"
  },
  "siteRefreshMode": {
    "refreshModeId": 2,
    "refreshMode": "NORMAL"
  },
  "updateInitTime": 1441930019,
  "nextUpdate": 1441930919,
  "code": 0,
  "itemRefreshInfo": [
    {
      "memItemId": MEMITEMID,
      "itemSuggestedFlow": {
        "suggestedFlowId": 1,
        "suggestedFlow": "NOT_REFRESHABLE"
      },
      "itemSuggestedFlowReason": {
        "suggestedFlowReasonId": 4,
        "suggestedFlowReason": "REFRESH_IN_PROGRESS"
      },
      "errorCode": 0,
      "retryCount": 0
    },
    {
      "memItemId": MEMITEMID,
      "itemSuggestedFlow": {
        "suggestedFlowId": 1,
        "suggestedFlow": "NOT_REFRESHABLE"
      },
      "itemSuggestedFlowReason": {
        "suggestedFlowReasonId": 4,
        "suggestedFlowReason": "REFRESH_IN_PROGRESS"
      },
      "errorCode": 0,
      "retryCount": 0
    }
  ],
  "noOfRetry": 0,
  "isMFAInputRequired": false,
  "siteAddStatus": {
    "siteAddStatusId": 15,
    "siteAddStatus": "ADD_FAILURE"
  }
}
```

What is this `"siteAddStatus": "ADD_FAILURE"`? what does that mean? I can't find any documentation online.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This siteAddStatus tells that the site addition was failed, this can be happen because of 3 reasons.

1. There could have been any Site Issue, which resulted into failure of add account.
2. If it is an MFA site and user is supposed to enter some additional login details and it was not provided in time or user might have entered invalid credentials.
3. There was some use case which was not handled(though, this happens very rarely)

As I can see that you have started a refresh of that particular account, and you have to look for '**siteRefreshStatus**' field's value and here it says 'REFRESH_TRIGGERED' means refresh process for this account has been triggered successfully. Now you have to follow next steps. You can always refer to the [Add Account Flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account) and [Refresh flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Refresh_Site_Account).